# Ziparchive for multiple files into memory stream

Tags: c#, memorystream, c#-ziparchive

I have studied the answers to similar questions, but have not seen one where multiple files are gathered into an ziparchive for transmission to download. The following gives no errors but does not return a recognizable zip file.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAZipOfFiles()
{
      var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
      var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

      List<string> filepaths = await GetSomeFiles();
      using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
      {
          foreach (string filepath in filepaths)
          {
               string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
               using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath))
               using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(archive.CreateEntry(filename).Open()))
               {
                    writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
               }
          }
      }
      memoryStream.Position = 0;
      response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
      response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = memoryStream.Length;
      response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
      {
          FileName = "TheFile.zip")
      };
      response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
     return response;
}
```

Comment: Side note, but when you break out the zipping part as a separate method it becomes a lot easier to (unit)test.

Answer (score 4):

I see you are using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, which not only are useless for your purpose, but may create encoding problems because they are specifically used to read and write Text files.

If you need to add to your archive any kind of file and not only plain text files they may corrupt the data when reading/writing.

Instead, just copy raw streams to archive entries:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAZipOfFiles()
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    List<string> filepaths = await GetSomeFiles();
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (string filepath in filepaths)
        {
             string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
             var entry = archive.CreateEntry(filename);
             using (var file = File.OpenRead(filename))
             using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
             {
                  await file.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
             }
        }
    }
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = memoryStream.Length;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "TheFile.zip")
    };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my problem was on the typescript side.

I did change the code, replacing:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filepath))
using (StreamWriter writer = new 
StreamWriter(archive.CreateEntry(filename).Open()))
{
    writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

with the simpler:

```
archive.CreateEntryFromFile(filepath, Path.GetFileName(filepath));
```